# Dynamically updating dropdown menu in React

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

Using fetch, I want to dynamically populate the City material-ui dropdwon (Select) when I select a value from the State dropdown,  but could not do so. When I do the same without using the fetch, it works fine. I think the problem is with the promise being returned by the fetch call. There is no problem in the fetch call as I can see the list of cities in return. Please suggest how to do it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import {Select, MenuItem} from '@material-ui/core';

import './App.css';

export function getStates() {
    return [
        {name: 'California', id: "1"},
        {name: 'New York', id: "2"},
    ]
}

function Home() {

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
      createStyles({
              formControl: {
                        margin: theme.spacing(1),
                        minWidth: 120,
                      },
              selectEmpty: {
                marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
              },
    }),
);

const [State, setState] = React.useState([]);
const [cities, setCities] = React.useState([]);

const selectStyle = makeStyles(theme => ({
          root: {
                textDecoration: 'none',
                color: 'red',
                alignItems: 'center',
                fontWeight: "bold",
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "space-around",
                fontSize: 18,
                margin: 0,
                '&:hover': {
                    textDecoration: 'none'
                }
            },
}));

function getCities() {
    var s = '' // JSON body goes here
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const cities = [];
        try {
            const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080', 
                 {
                    method : "POST",
                    headers: {"content-type": "text/plain"},
                    body: s
                }
            );
            const data = await res.json();
            console.log("state response status: " + res.status)

            for(var key in data.cities) {
                cities.push({id: key, name: data.cities[key]})
            }
            return cities;
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log("Fetch Exception: " + err)
        }
    }
    const cities = fetchData();
    return cities;
}

const handleStateChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent< { value: unknown} >) => {
    setState(event.target.value);
    const r = getCities();
    setCities([r]);
}

const fixed_states = getStates();
const classes = useStyles()
const selectClass = selectStyle()

    return (
        <div className="main-select">
        <container>
        <FormControl required className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="sel">State</InputLabel>
        <Select labelId="state_select_labelid" id="state_select_id" name="state_select_name" onChange={handleStateChange} className={selectClass.root}>
        {fixed_states.map(({id, name}, index) => (
         < MenuItem key={id} value={name}>
                {name}
            </MenuItem>
            )) }
        </Select>
        <FormHelperText></FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>

        <FormControl required className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="city_input_label_id">City</InputLabel>
        <Select labelId="city_select_labelid" id="city_select_id" name="city_select_name">
        {cities.map(({id, name}, index) => (
         < MenuItem key={id} value={name}>
                {name}
            </MenuItem>
            ))}

        </Select>
        <FormHelperText></FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>

        </container>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

You code:

```
 const handleStateChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent< { value: unknown} >) => {
        setState(event.target.value);
        const r = getCities();
        setCities([r]);
    }
```

but **getCities** return array of cities and then you set array cities in state like array of array.
So just update argument in setCities row to

```
const handleStateChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent< { value: unknown} >) => {
            setState(event.target.value);
            const r = getCities();
            setCities(r);
        }
```

Comment: Yes, that is the mistake. I corrected it on my local machine and now it says the following:
TypeError: cities.map is not a function
After your comment, I realized that I got rid of the above error by converting the cities array again to the array, which was wrong. Being a newbie to React, I thought I need to reinforce the the type of cities to array by mentioning [] while calling setCitites.

Comment: You get **cities.map is not a function** because cities = undefined at beginning, so use can use [optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) just update you map function to `{cities?.map(({id, name}, index) => ( ...code... ))}`